# MySQL LOCATE - POSITION returns wrong number

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT 
    POSITION(
            '^email' IN b.form) + CHAR_LENGTH('^email...') as 'email_start',
    LOCATE('~',b.form, POSITION(
            '^email' IN b.form) + CHAR_LENGTH('^email...')) as 'email_end',
    (LOCATE('~',b.form, POSITION(
            '^email' IN b.form) + CHAR_LENGTH('^email...')) -

    POSITION(
            '^email' IN b.form) + CHAR_LENGTH('^email...')) as 'num_chars',
    b.form as 'Form'

    FROM
        f98_bookingdates as bd
    JOIN
        f98_booking as b
        on b.booking_id = bd.booking_id

    LIMIT 20
```

And it returns:

```
email_start    email_end   num_chars
       444           474          48
```

email_start is correct. email_end is correct.

But 474 - 444 is not 48...

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an extra parenthesis around the second part of the calculation:

```
(LOCATE('~',b.form, POSITION(
            '^email' IN b.form) + CHAR_LENGTH('^email...')) -    
(POSITION(
         '^email' IN b.form) + CHAR_LENGTH('^email...'))) as 'num_chars'
```

The reson is that you want to calculate the starting position first and subtract this from the end position.